# Can PyCharm follow file URIs from terminal?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm 2018.3.3 and I would like to follow hyperlinks from terminal. Everything works well for hyperlinks that start with `http://` or `https://`. Whereas hyperlinks that start with `file://` are correctly highlighted but nothing happens when I click on them.

[image]

If I use the default terminal of my environment (i.e. GNOME terminal) then everything works as expected. I am able to follow all the hyperlinks with `Ctrl` + `Left click`.

How to make hyperlinks (file URIs) work in PyCharm terminal?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Please read the comment below, this is probably not the main issue. PyCharm allows you to change the shell, but not the terminal emulator.

---

The problem isn't with PyCharm itself, it's with the underlying terminal emulator that PyCharm uses. This is [configurable in the settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-system-console.html).

Following the instructions in the link above, you could switch PyCharm to always use GNOME terminal. This would resolve your issue.

Otherwise, try googling this question for the specific terminal emulator that is configured in PyCharm.

Comment: Thanks! I follow your advice. I switch PyCharm to use GNOME terminal instead of Bash (i.e. shell path set to `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` instead of `/bin/bash`). I can't open any PyCharm terminal with this configuration. This was expected since PyCharm allow you to configure the shell to use but not the terminal emulator (which is a different thing). The problem is not the underlying shell that PyCharm uses but PyCharm terminal emulator. I'm googling if it is possible to configure this terminal emulator and haven't found any result so far. What else could I try?

Comment: Ah my bad, I guess I was confused about the difference. I'm not sure then.